# Choosing partials with Mustache

Tags: mustache

If I'm rendering HTML from a mustache script and some partials, can I choose which partial to use depending on the the data being rendered?

Eg:

```
data = {"posts": [
  {"type":"text", "body":"I'm text"},
  {"type":"image", "uri":"http://placekitten.com/200/300"}
]}
```

With a base template of something like:

```
<ul class="posts">
  <li>
  {{#posts}}
    {{> {{type}}}}
  {{/posts}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then `text.mustache`:

```
<p>{{body}}</p>
```

And `image.mustache`:

```
<img src="{{uri}}" />
```

And this would render as:

```
<ul class="posts">
  <li>
    <p>I'm text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Am I missing something here? Should I be attempting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking here comes down on the "logic" side of the line, and as such, is something Mustache tries to avoid. That's not to say there's no way of doing it, it just probably isn't the way you'd think :)

In Mustache, the right answer to a lot of more advanced usage is "prepare your view". This is no exception. I'd prolly do it like this:

```
function addHelpers(posts) {
    for (var i = 0, l = posts.length; i < l; i++) {
        posts[i].isText  = posts[i].type === 'text';
        posts[i].isImage = posts[i].type === 'image';
        posts[i].isVideo = posts[i].type === 'video';
    }
    return posts;
}

data = {"posts": [
  {"type":"text", "body":"I'm text"},
  {"type":"image", "uri":"http://placekitten.com/200/300"}
]}

data.posts = addHelpers(data.posts);
```

Then your base template would look something like this:

```
<ul class="posts">
  {{# posts }}
    <li>
      {{# isText  }}{{> text  }}{{/ isText  }}
      {{# isImage }}{{> image }}{{/ isImage }}
      {{# isVideo }}{{> video }}{{/ isVideo }}
    </li>
  {{/ posts }}
</ul>
```